# Unable to create core : _version_ field

Tags: solr

I have *version* field in schema file. I am hitting the below error message when 
creating core:
Unable to create core [corename] Caused by: *version* field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" or docValues="true", stored="true" and multiValued="false" (*version* does not exist)
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

figured out solr.LongField and solr.SortableLongField are deprecated. Used solr.TrieLongField and it works fine

Comment: This should NOT be the reason for the message. Perhaps there was an XML formatting error of some sorts as well.